# Jenkins with Mercurial doesn't use the newest revision

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, continuous-integration

I use Jenkins to do a build process.
It's integrated with Mercurial and it polls for changes periodically.

But now what problem I have.

Let's say I pushed 2 changesets into Mercurial repository. Jenkins polls it and finds them. In job page, both changes and revision show the newest one.
But in build, Jenkins mysteriously uses the second newest changeset.
And poller then doesn't run another build, because the previous one was meant for the newest changeset.
So until I notice, there is not newest version.

I attach some lines from Jenkins console:

```
[workspace] $ hg showconfig paths.default
[workspace] $ hg pull --rev default
pulling from ...
no changes found
[workspace] $ hg update --clean --rev default
2 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
[workspace] $ hg log --rev . --template {node}
[workspace] $ hg log --rev . --template {rev}
[workspace] $ hg log --rev ec412428d4e3b8901f5f14bb0b5af418c75cebdd
changeset:   19:ec412428d4e3
user:        ...
date:        Mon Jul 28 13:23:21 2014 +0200
summary:     (Name of the second newest change)
```

And in Job page

```
Changes 
1. (Name of the newest change) (detail / hgweb)
```

Can it be somehow set, so that Jenkins always built the newest version, and not the next one to the last build?